# Trigger a one-time sequence based on another column

Tags: google-sheets

This is probably an unusual question but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in Google Sheets.

I have a column A where the user can enter 1 or 0, and a column B that keeps a running total all of the values entered so far on column A.

I have a column C that I would like to create a one-time sequence that counts up to 6 in the subsequent cells, starting once column B reaches 3 or more.

I figured out a (probably crappy) way to do that, but the formula I have causes this sequence to keep looping once it finishes.

Is there a way to limit the sequence to occurring only one time? Here's a version of the problem in a Google sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eznw1kkW6IRezB6TVnBdXK6tiEFxI2PaTBLx4DMnWmE/copy

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out! May not necessarily be the most elegant solution, but I created a new column that basically uses MATCH() to find the position of the first instance of the maximum in the sequence and only copy over the values if the row number is less than or equal to that.

```
=if((row(C2)-1)<=match(6,$C$2:$C$30,0),C2,0)
```

Spreadsheet updated with the new row.